# I am planning to test a LMS application with 100 and 200 concurrent users,what is the minimum bandwidth to run this load test

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

In the load test the following scenarios are included
users viewing video, listening to audio, viewing pdf, ppt,etc
100 and 200 concurrent users with these scenarios what is the minimum bandwidth(mbps) for these scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should have some form of [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) or [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreemen) stating something like:

> user with mobile phone connected to 3G network should have response time not more than 2 seconds

So you need to determine the slowest supported network type and [simulate users connected to this networks type](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test) accessing your application. You can use [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) to automatically fail the requests which response time exceeds acceptable thresholds.

Here are the most popular throttled data presets which can be useful:

> **Bandwidth** |                                **cps**
>
> GPRS | 21888
>
> 3G | 2688000
>
> 4G | 19200000
>
> WIFI 802.11a/g |   6912000
>
> ADSL | 1024000
>
> 100 Mb LAN | 12800000
>
> Gigabit Lan    | 128000000